# How to include navigation.phtml file in custom page?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have added in mywallet.xml file below codes -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account>
    <!-- Mage_Sales -->
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">

        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mywallet">
            <name>mywallet_index</name>
            <path>mywallet/index/index</path>
            <label>My Wallet</label>
        </action>
    </reference>        
</customer_account>
<mywallet_index_index>   
<reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template>  </action>
</reference>   
<reference name="content">   
  <block type="mywallet/index" name="mywallet_index" template="mywallet/index.phtml"/>   
</reference>   
</mywallet_index_index>
</layout>
```

But no effect. Links are not displayed on custom page. Can anyone tell me how to display?
[image]
Below is my Order History Page -

[image]

Comment: Have you created mywallet module?

Comment: @Rakesh Yes, I have created mywallet module

Comment: Have you try with below code?

Comment: @Rakesh I tried but no effect

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below xml, remove original account edit and address book,

```
 <customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Sales -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">

            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mywallet">
                <name>mywallet_index</name>
                <path>mywallet/index/index</path>
                <label>My Wallet</label>
            </action>
        </reference>        
    </customer_account>
```

Comment: I tried, but no effect.

Comment: Have you check using http://siteurl.com/mywallet/index/index This handle is working or not?

Comment: please show your full xml file which have used in your site?

Comment: It is working perfectly. I have added screenshot for reference. Only navigation link is not displayed.

Comment: Are you looking for set above link in left side?

Comment: have you try your custom module url is working or not?

Comment: Custom module url is working fine. One more screenshot I have added for reference. That screenshot is of Order History Page. In that navigation menu is included.

Comment: ok i will check it.